# How does "return 1" show "1" in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, monads, type-inference, ghci

This is what I get when type `return 1` in GHCi.

```
> return 1
1
```

Since I didn't specify the type of `return`, type of `return 1` is `Monad m, Num a => m a`

How does GHCi show `1` even though there is no instance for `Show`?

Comment: The default Monad is IO. There is no Show for IO, but when you return an IO, GHCi will not Show it, but run it, and Show the result (an Integer here, which does have Show).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Monad m => m` defaults to `IO`, that's how.

Then the IO action is performed, does no I/O, and returns the value.

Ghci has two output modes of operation: when the evaluated value has type `IO a` and when it doesn't. In the first case, the IO action is performed, and the value of type `a` produced by the action is shown. In the second case, the evaluated value is just shown.

Since you're in Ghci, the type of `return 1 :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a` is actually `IO Integer`. `m` defaults to `IO`, and `a` defaults to `Integer`, so the `Integer` `1` is shown.

Enable the GHCi showing you the types, with `ghci> :set +t`, then try `return 1.0`. It returns `Double`, and `Double`s also have the `Show` instance.

```
> return 1
1
it :: Integer

> return 1.0
1.0
it :: Double

> return "3"
"3"
it :: [Char]

> print "3"
"3"
it :: ()
```